# Error with SonarQube Visual Studio Code Coverage Import

Tags: .net, sonarqube

I am seeing errors when importing Coverage results from one specific solution. Others seem to work fine. I have been using version 5.1 of the C# plug in and I have just tried 5.2 RC, but am still seeing the same issue.

The error seems to be related to the source file having less lines than the coverage file seems to indicate. I've seen a similar issue referenced here, which looks like it was resolved, but not for me...;

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarqube/Xju6ichZe_k

Any help or guidance you could offer would be much appreciate as this is the final step to me getting useful info out of SonarQube.

---

The error is;

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't create measure for line 12 for
>   file
>   'E:/b/3/_work/25/s/Maples.eServices.UI/Maples.eServices.UI.Services/TodayNotification/AggregatedEmailModels/ContactWithChanges.cs'
>   with 9 lines
>
> 2016-04-25T18:42:08.8051671Z 19:42:08.617 INFO  - Sensor
>   org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpSensor (done) | time=3703ms
>   2016-04-25T18:42:08.8051671Z 19:42:08.617 INFO  - Sensor
>   org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpCodeCoverageProvider$CSharpCoverageReportImportSensor
>   2016-04-25T18:42:08.8051671Z 19:42:08.617 INFO  - Parsing the Visual
>   Studio coverage XML report
>   E:\b\3_work\25\TestResults\svctfsbuild_KYTFS15BLD02 2016-04-25
>   19_38_27\In\KYTFS15BLD02\svctfsbuild_KYTFS15BLD02 2016-04-25
>   19_37_19.coveragexml   2016-04-25T18:42:08.9145352Z 19:42:08.773 INFO 
>   - Adding this code coverage report to the cache for later reuse: E:\b\3_work\25\TestResults\svctfsbuild_KYTFS15BLD02 2016-04-25
>   19_38_27\In\KYTFS15BLD02\svctfsbuild_KYTFS15BLD02 2016-04-25
>   19_37_19.coveragexml   2016-04-25T18:42:09.5707468Z INFO:
>
> 2016-04-25T18:42:09.5707468Z INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
>   2016-04-25T18:42:09.5707468Z INFO:
>
> 2016-04-25T18:42:09.5707468Z Total time: 1:30.185s
>   2016-04-25T18:42:09.6801267Z Final Memory: 10M/235M
>   2016-04-25T18:42:09.6801267Z INFO:
>
> 2016-04-25T18:42:09.6801267Z ##[error]ERROR: Error during Sonar runner
>   execution   2016-04-25T18:42:09.6801267Z ##[error]org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar   2016-04-25T18:42:09.6801267Z ##[error]at
>   org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
>   2016-04-25T18:42:09.6801267Z ##[error]at
>   org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
>   2016-04-25T18:42:09.6801267Z ##[error]at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>   2016-04-25T18:42:09.6801267Z ##[error]at
>   org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
>   2016-04-25T18:42:09.6801267Z ##[error]at
>   org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
>   2016-04-25T18:42:09.6801267Z ##[error]at
>   org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
>   2016-04-25T18:42:09.6801267Z ##[error]at
>   org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
>   2016-04-25T18:42:09.6801267Z ##[error]at
>   org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
>   2016-04-25T18:42:09.6801267Z ##[error]at
>   org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
>   2016-04-25T18:42:09.6801267Z ##[error]at
>   org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:53)
>   2016-04-25T18:42:09.6801267Z ##[error]Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't create measure for line 12 for
>   file
>   'E:/b/3/_work/25/s/Maples.eServices.UI/Maples.eServices.UI.Services/TodayNotification/AggregatedEmailModels/ContactWithChanges.cs'
>   with 9 lines   2016-04-25T18:42:09.6801267Z ##[error]at
>   org.sonar.batch.sensor.coverage.CoverageExclusions.validateMaxLine(CoverageExclusions.java:158)
>   2016-04-25T18:42:09.6801267Z ##[error]at
>   org.sonar.batch.sensor.coverage.CoverageExclusions.validate(CoverageExclusions.java:129)
>   2016-04-25T18:42:09.6801267Z ##[error]at
>   org.sonar.batch.deprecated.DeprecatedSensorContext.saveMeasure(DeprecatedSensorContext.java:204)
>   2016-04-25T18:42:09.6801267Z ##[error]at
>   org.sonar.plugins.dotnet.tests.CoverageReportImportSensor.analyze(CoverageReportImportSensor.java:103)
>   2016-04-25T18:42:09.6801267Z ##[error]at
>   org.sonar.plugins.dotnet.tests.CoverageReportImportSensor.analyse(CoverageReportImportSensor.java:74)
>   2016-04-25T18:42:09.6801267Z ##[error]at
>   org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:58)
>   2016-04-25T18:42:09.6801267Z ##[error]at
>   org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:50)
>   2016-04-25T18:42:09.6801267Z ##[error]at
>   org.sonar.batch.phases.PhaseExecutor.execute(PhaseExecutor.java:102)
>   2016-04-25T18:42:09.6801267Z ##[error]at
>   org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:185)
>   2016-04-25T18:42:09.6801267Z ##[error]at
>   org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
>   2016-04-25T18:42:09.6801267Z ##[error]at
>   org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:120)
>   2016-04-25T18:42:09.6801267Z ##[error]at
>   org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:264)
>   2016-04-25T18:42:09.6801267Z ##[error]at
>   org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:259)
>   2016-04-25T18:42:09.6801267Z ##[error]at
>   org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:257)
>   2016-04-25T18:42:09.6801267Z ##[error]at
>   org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:249)
>   2016-04-25T18:42:09.6801267Z ##[error]at
>   org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
>   2016-04-25T18:42:09.6801267Z ##[error]at
>   org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.startComponents(ProjectScanContainer.java:127)
>   2016-04-25T18:42:09.6801267Z ##[error]at
>   org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:120)
>   2016-04-25T18:42:09.6801267Z ##[error]at
>   org.sonar.batch.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:55)
>   2016-04-25T18:42:09.6801267Z ##[error]at
>   org.sonar.batch.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)
>   2016-04-25T18:42:09.6801267Z ##[error]at
>   org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
>   2016-04-25T18:42:09.6801267Z ##[error]at
>   org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:120)
>   2016-04-25T18:42:09.6801267Z ##[error]at
>   org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:122)
>   2016-04-25T18:42:09.6957435Z ##[error]at
>   org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:119)
>   2016-04-25T18:42:09.6957435Z ##[error]at
>   org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:79)
>   2016-04-25T18:42:09.6957435Z ##[error]at
>   org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
>   2016-04-25T18:42:09.6957435Z ##[error]at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   2016-04-25T18:42:09.6957435Z ##[error]at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   2016-04-25T18:42:09.6957435Z ##[error]at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   2016-04-25T18:42:09.6957435Z ##[error]at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   2016-04-25T18:42:09.6957435Z ##[error]at
>   org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
>   2016-04-25T18:42:09.6957435Z ##[error]... 9 more
>   2016-04-25T18:42:09.6957435Z ##[error]ERROR:
>   2016-04-25T18:42:09.6957435Z ##[error]ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Runner
>   using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>   2016-04-25T18:42:09.6957435Z ##[error]The SonarQube Scanner did not
>   complete successfully   2016-04-25T18:42:09.6957435Z 19:42:09.617 
>   Creating a summary markdown file...   2016-04-25T18:42:09.6957435Z ##[error]Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1   2016-04-25T18:42:09.8207681Z ##[error]Unexpected exit code received
>   from batch file: 1

The relevant part(s) of the `coveragexml` file are;

```
     <function id="215992" token="0x6000cce" name="get_ContactId()" type_name="ContactWithChanges" block_coverage="0.00" line_coverage="0.00" blocks_covered="0" blocks_not_covered="3" lines_covered="0" lines_partially_covered="0" lines_not_covered="1">
      <ranges>
        <range source_id="213" covered="no" start_line="5" start_column="26" end_line="5" end_column="27" />
        <range source_id="213" covered="no" start_line="5" start_column="28" end_line="5" end_column="32" />
      </ranges>
    </function>
    <function id="216018" token="0x6000ccf" name="set_ContactId(int)" type_name="ContactWithChanges" block_coverage="0.00" line_coverage="0.00" blocks_covered="0" blocks_not_covered="3" lines_covered="0" lines_partially_covered="0" lines_not_covered="1">
      <ranges>
        <range source_id="213" covered="no" start_line="5" start_column="31" end_line="5" end_column="32" />
        <range source_id="213" covered="no" start_line="5" start_column="33" end_line="5" end_column="37" />
      </ranges>
    </function>
    <function id="216032" token="0x6000cd0" name="get_DisplayName()" type_name="ContactWithChanges" block_coverage="0.00" line_coverage="0.00" blocks_covered="0" blocks_not_covered="3" lines_covered="0" lines_partially_covered="0" lines_not_covered="1">
      <ranges>
        <range source_id="213" covered="no" start_line="5" start_column="33" end_line="5" end_column="37" />
      </ranges>
    </function>
    <function id="216058" token="0x6000cd1" name="set_DisplayName(string)" type_name="ContactWithChanges" block_coverage="0.00" line_coverage="0.00" blocks_covered="0" blocks_not_covered="3" lines_covered="0" lines_partially_covered="0" lines_not_covered="14">
      <ranges>
        <range source_id="213" covered="no" start_line="6" start_column="36" end_line="6" end_column="37" />
        <range source_id="213" covered="no" start_line="6" start_column="38" end_line="6" end_column="42" />
        <range source_id="213" covered="no" start_line="14" start_column="7" end_line="20" end_column="10" />
      </ranges>
    </function>
    <function id="216072" token="0x6000cd2" name="ContactWithChanges()" type_name="ContactWithChanges" block_coverage="0.00" line_coverage="0.00" blocks_covered="0" blocks_not_covered="4" lines_covered="0" lines_partially_covered="0" lines_not_covered="15">
      <ranges>
        <range source_id="213" covered="no" start_line="6" start_column="38" end_line="6" end_column="42" />
        <range source_id="213" covered="no" start_line="12" start_column="5" end_line="12" end_column="41" />
        <range source_id="213" covered="no" start_line="14" start_column="7" end_line="20" end_column="10" />
      </ranges>
    </function>
    <source_file id="213" path="E:\b\3\_work\25\s\Maples.eServices.UI\Maples.eServices.UI.Services\TodayNotification\AggregatedEmailModels\ContactWithChanges.cs">
    </source_file>
```

The source code is;

```
namespace Maples.eServices.UI.Services.TodayNotification.AggregatedEmailModels
{
  public class ContactWithChanges
  {
    public int ContactId { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

that happened to my team with an upgrade to sonarqube 6.2.
We're using Jenkins to build and run the analysis.
I wiped the workspace and rerun the jobs and everything ran succesfully again.

**Random guess :**
Probably due to how coverage scanning is now fluent (additive).
taken out of the [source code](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/84fcbdd5a897a26faf0177e57f30c8f611fdd732/sonar-plugin-api/src/main/java/org/sonar/api/batch/sensor/coverage/NewCoverage.java)

```
/**
 * This class is used to report code coverage on files.
 * 
 * Example:
 * 
 * <pre>
 *   sensorContext.newCoverage().onFile(file)
       .lineHits(1, 2)
       .lineHits(2, 5)
       .lineHits(3, 0)
       . ...
       .conditions(3, 4, 2)
       .conditions(12, 2, 2)
       . ...
       .save();
 *     
 * </pre>
 * 
 * Since 6.2 you can save several reports for the same file and reports will be merged using the following "additive" strategy:
 * <ul>
 *   <li>Line hits are cumulated</li>
 *   <li>We keep the max for condition coverage. Examples: 2/4 + 2/4 = 2/4, 2/4 + 3/4 = 3/4</li>
 * </ul>
 * 
 * @since 5.2
```